# Ruby: why does `puts true and false` return true?

Tags: ruby, boolean, boolean-logic

In Ruby, I've just noticed that:

- `puts true and false` returns `true`, while
- `puts (true and false)` and `puts false and true` return both `false`.

What is the logic/reason behind this behaviour?

Comment: Can it be because `puts` is not a keyword - its a method that returns nil? Because `true and false` give nil without puts. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-puts

Comment: Technically, I'd say it returns `nil`, not `true` or `false`, and outputs `true`. e.g. if you execute the statement `result = (puts true and false)`, `result` will be nil. This is because `puts` returns `nil`. `nil and false` evaluates to `nil`.

Comment: The first one doesn't return `true`, it prints `true`. The second examples do not return `false`, they print `false. You are confusing the return value with the printed value.

Comment: @sawa: Indeed, you are right. What got me confused is that I used an online IDE that didn't output return values…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `puts` binds stronger than `and`: your code is equal to

```
(puts true) and false
true
#=> nil
```

You can check operators [precedence in docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html).

To get what you could use `&&`, which has higher precedence than `and`:

```
puts true && false
false
#=> nil
```